# How to trim slash using Expression in SSRS

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using Matrix to render it into  excel  and in one of the Cell I am getting the Date from the database in format of yyyy/mm e.g 2015/01 , but Client want "/"  to be trim and should be displayed as yyyymm , i.e 201501, what could be expression for it in SSRS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StrDate = "2015/01"  
StrDate = StrDate.replace("/","")  
OUTPUT---> StrDate = "201501"
```

Comment: How Can I do in SSRs using expression ?